# Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my Android application, I have two activity classes.  I have a button on the first one and I want to show the second when it is clicked, but I get an error.  Here are the classes:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.order);

    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, OrderScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

The second class that should show when the button is clicked, but never does:

```
public class OrderScreen extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order);

    Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);

    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

How do I create a button that will show the second activity?

Comment: Do you get an error when you compile or run time?  In either case, what is the error?

Comment: This was a run time error. The emulator gave the generic "the application has stopped unexpectedly" error, but using the debugger, it showed a "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {class name} have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: It is a very common bug that people forget to add their activity into Manifest.xml but there should be way to enter it automatically.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The issue was the **OrderScreen** `Activity` wasn't added to the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).  Once I added that as an application node, it worked properly.

```
<activity android:name=".OrderScreen" />
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is needed?

Comment: @LouisRhys all activities need to be declared in the manifest file. See `Description` section here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 162):

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".OrderScreen" />
```

Comment: Why did people upvote this answer from months later?

Comment: @Jaykul see the edit from 2013 in the accepted answer

Answer (score 16):

----**FirstActivity.java**-----

```
    package com.mindscripts.eid;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,OrderScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 }
}
```

---

---**OrderScreen.java**---

```
    package com.mindscripts.eid;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;



    public class OrderScreen extends Activity {
@Override



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_class);
    Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

 }
}
```

---

---**AndroidManifest.xml**----

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mindscripts.eid"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OrderScreen"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer for the benefit of the OP

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,SecondActivty.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

context: refer to current activity context,

please make sure that you have added activity in android manifest file.

Following code for adding activity in android manifest file

```
<Activity name=".SecondActivity">
</Activity>
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment GetUserNumber{536bc00c} not attached to Activity.

Answer (score 4):

```
<activity android:name="[packagename optional].ActivityClassName"></activity>
```

Simply adding the activity which we want to switch to should be placed in the manifest file

Answer (score 3):

When you create any activity in android file you have to specify it in  AndroidManifest.xml like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyCreativityActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity android:name=".OrderScreen"></activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_me);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Add SecondActivity class in your menifest file.

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})?

Answer (score 2):

add the activity in your manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".OrderScreen" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".OrderScreen" />
```

In the Java Code where you have to place intent code

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OrderScreen.class);
```

Comment: You are missing one closing bracket in `startActivity`
It should be like this:
`startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OrderScreen.class));`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the context of the view that did the calling.
Example:

```
Button orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.order);

orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(/*FirstActivity.this*/ view.getContext(), OrderScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

});
```

Comment: The method getContext() is undefined for the type MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.Android.SubActivity");
startActivity(i);
```