# How to create an external intent to an application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-intent

I have 3 related questions that can all be answered together:
1. How can I check the applications installed on the clients device?
2. How can I create an intent to an application (ex. Maps, SMS, Facebook, Words With Friends, etc.)?
3. How can I create a specific intent for the dictionary.com app that lets me search for a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some of the answers you seek .... tada :

1 - List installed application : http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-list-of-installed-application.html

2 - new intent for default sms application : [launch sms application with an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372248/launch-sms-application-with-an-intent)

3 - i'm not sure but this could help [Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)

Comment: For number 2 how do I do a different application (ex. Words with Friends)?