# how to perform a condition the basis of item selection on two spinners?

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners in my app. I want that if i select  option "first" from spinner 1 and option "second" from spinner 2, then the action gets performed. But it show "NUMBERFORMATEXCEPTION".

Here's the code

```
  if (((spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()=="first" &&        
(s2.getItemAtPosition(id).toString()=="second"))))
   {

       tv.setText(String.valueOf(gmtomilli(x)));
   }
```

This code has the error, if i omit this code,  then the app works fine,without action

Comment: spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("first"), only use == when comparing numbers

Answer (score 4):

Do `String` comparison using `equals`.

```
spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()=="first"
```

instead use:

```
spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("first")
```

Similarly for:

```
s2.getItemAtPosition(id).toString()=="second"
```

instead use:

```
s2.getItemAtPosition(id).toString().equals("second")
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for more information.

`==` compares references,not the values. In your case, you want to check for the value equality, not the reference equality.

---

EDIT:

Since you have mentioned that your code is generating `NumberFormatException`, I probably believe that either `pos` or `id` are of `String` type generating the `NumberFormatException`.

---

EDIT 2:

As per the your comment:

```
float x=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(et.getText()));
```

Your `getText()` is returning a `String` that can't be actually parsed into a `float`. Try checking if the content is actually a `float` in `String` format.
Besides, use `String.trim()` before parsing to ensure your `String` doesn't contain any leading or trailing whitespaces that's generating the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @user1470125 could you please edit your question to provide a few more details,like what type is `pos`,what type is `id`,which exact line is giving you `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Both pos and id are globally declared.......      public int pos=2;
 public int id=1;

Comment: @user1470125 you might want to post your entire code, along with the logcat content, because the information you have provided doesn't seem to generate a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: The other code is working fine. Made the following changes, still same error.        
                                                                             if ((spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==2) && ((s2.getSelectedItemPosition()==1)))
       {
        
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(gmtomilli(x)+"mg"));

Comment: @user1470125 what is `gmtomilli()` content? what is `x`? If you want better help, kindly post your code. It'll be easier to find the error. Else, I'll have to keep guessing.

Comment: float x=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(et.getText()));    gmtomilli is a function

Comment: Yes,thanks the error is in that line only.:-) But i cant get a fix to that. How to check whether that is float in a string format. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: You need to pass a number to that `EditText`,which you are apparently not doing.

Comment: Thanks alot!!!! The app worked. But now when i click on the button, the app force closes. The if condition is in the onCreate function. Is that the erro?

Comment: Check the logcat. It will tell you the reason for the force close,and which line is probably causing it.

Comment: This is the error-      06-21 15:48:46.509: E/AndroidRuntime(2260): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCreate(View) in the activity class sks.and.ListActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'conv'

Comment: I've told you to post your code and your logcat content. Post a new question, as it is a new problem, this question is done as far as the initial `NumerFormatException` problem is concerned. It is really really tough for someone to help without actually looking at your code.

Comment: Start a new question. Post your code, and your logcat content. This current question has been solved I believe.

Comment: Oh...sorry. Sure. Will do. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: And look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803127/how-do-i-assign-a-button-to-an-activity-in-java , for the new problem that is coming in your program. I believe there is no `Button` with the id `conv` in your xml.

Comment: Posted a new question. The button is there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136383/using-to-spinners-app-works-fine-but-when-the-button-is-clicked-error-is-displ