# Relaunching the Android app to the same state

Tags: android

I have android app with 3 Activities.

**Scenario:** Home Screen - >Launch App - >Activity A ->Activity B -> Activity C - >Press Home button -> Home Screen - >Launch App

I am expecting Activity C to be shown. but app is getting relaunched.

In iOS 4.0 or Above app comes to same state on relaunching. In Android do we need to do something extra to get this behavior?

One More Scenario: If you push the App in debug mode then above behavior is not seen. If you create apk and push, then only app is not retaining its state.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle) documentation

Also take a look at onPause() and onResume() methods. You will have to override them to store your app's state. In this case, you may have to store which activity was in the foreground when the app was closed.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity) to see how to start an activity. You can start an activity in your onResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to play around with the state of an Activity you have to work with Manifest file.
At the time of registering the Activity in Manifest you define various information related to the activity state.
If you wish to make some changes in the launch you need to work it up there.