# How to get instance of main class android?

Tags: java, android

I have one class which is calling other classes, this class is my main. Is it possible to get somehow instance of this main class, that in others classes i could call main class methods ?

If yes so how this should be done in android with java?

Thanks.

Comment: is that main class is Activity...?

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating the other classes in your main class, one approach would be to pass the current instance of your main class (i.e. `this') as a parameter to the constructors of the other classes, and have them store that reference for future use.

Alternately, you could simply pass the current instance of your main class as a parameter to the method you are calling, that needs to be able to call back.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Singleton**](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html) design pattern to achieve this.

Or if you want, you may use **Static methods** analogy for reusing the methods too.

*For example:*

```
public class Helper{
    public static void doSomething(){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Now in your other classes, use the above method as below:

```
Helper.doSomething();
```