# Android : switch background process to foreground

Tags: android, notifications, background-process

My app will create notification to notify user

when app is in background process for 8 hours

all i want is just switch process that create notification (background)

to foreground, what should i do ?

```
    // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    // intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle(xx);
        builder.setContentText(xx);
        builder.setTicker(xx);
        builder.setLargeIcon(xx);
        builder.setSmallIcon(xx);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        notification = builder.build();

    } else {

        notification = new Notification(xx, xx, 0);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, xx, xx, pendingIntent);

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartWorkingActivity2.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This will bring an existing task to the foreground without actually creating a new Activity. If your application is not running, it will create an instance of MyRootActivity and start it.

[Bring application to front after user clicks on home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button)