# Bring Android React Native App to Foreground On Receipt of Data Only Firebase Cloud Message

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am successfully using [Firebase Cloud Messaging with react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages) to send and receive data only messages between Android devices.

When a device receives a message, if the app is in the background or has been killed I would like to bring the app to the foreground. I am getting notifications that will display a `console.log()` under both circumstances, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to best approach 'waking up' the app / bring it to the foreground:

```js
  firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
    // Process your message as required
    console.log('You got a message!', message);
  });
}
```

The above code is executed as expected under both circumstances.

Are there React Native packages I can look at to help achieve what I'm trying to do or should I be considering having to write some Java?

#### Update

I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button) but not sure if it's possible to add code like this straight in to my React Native application?

#### Update 2

I have discovered [this package react-native-invoke-app](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app) that uses [HeadlessJS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android).

HeadlessJS requires you to use this code in your `index.js`:

`AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('SomeTaskName'));`

However `Firebase Cloud Messaging` already needs you to provide this line of code in the same place, which I'm guessing does the same thing as above:

`AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => backgroundMessaging);`

Following the `react-native-invoke-app` docs I am then placing the call to invoke my app inside the `firebase.messaging().onMessage((message))` callback like so:

```js
firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
    // Process your message as required
    invokeApp();
    console.log('You got message!', message);
  });
}
```

However this is not bringing my app to the foreground.

#### Update 3

I've now moved the `invokeApp()` call inside the Firebase `backgroundNotificationListener` function which is a headless task which seems like the correct approach:

```js
import invokeApp from 'react-native-invoke-app';

const incomingMessage = async (message) => {
  // handle your message
  invokeApp();
  return Promise.resolve();
}
export default incomingMessage;
```

But the app will still not come to the foreground when the `incomingMessage` function is called.

#### Update 4

I have raised [this](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app/issues/8) issue on the `react-native-invoke-app` github page which has more details on the issues I'm facing.

Comment: Correction: *foreground when a FCM data only message..

Comment: Hello Mr. Robot have you found proper solution for above becase I am also trying the same one

Comment: Hey @HardikDesai please check out backToForeground() method on react-native-callkeep try calling it in your HeadlessJS background function

Comment: Ok I will check that  do you have any code reference for headless

Comment: Yes, I am using a headless task with Firebsae Cloud Messaging: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage
https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `react-native-invoke-app` doesn't support Android versions > 8.

Comment: How did you fixed it for android > 8?

Comment: I actually changed the flow of the app so a notification appears when the app is in the background and clicking the notification brings the app to the foreground.

Comment: @Mr.Robot, can you give more details on how you changed the flow of your app?

Answer (score 3):

instead of `invokeapp();` you can describe a url scheme and to open the url related to that scheme, to make the app get opened and come in foreground.

**ON Android:**

add `<data android:scheme=“my-awesome-app” />` intent in `./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` under the ` tag.

**ON iOS**

1. open your xcode, bring the iOS project up and open `Info.plist` file in xcode.
2. add `URL types` row under the root key, then add an item e.g: `Item 0`, then `URL Schemes` then an item with a string value. (in our example it's my-awesome-app).
   Just like the picture below

Now after setting things the url scheme up, now you can call it like this.

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

Linking.openURL('my-awesome-app://');
```

you can use it everywhere you'd like.

[image: setting up scheme on iOS Info.plist]

Comment: Tried this. Deep linking on my side works fine, but still can't open app. Android 11 btw.

Comment: Anyone comes here and cant resolve this. Create another <intent-filter> and ad your  <data ... /> to there
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19928#issuecomment-463971415

Answer (score 1):

Using `react-native-invoke-app` should get the job done.

1. Make sure to have your `AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => backgroundMessaging);` on your root application component.
2. export the `backgroundMessaging` from whichever child component you have it in and import it to your app root component.
3. have the invokeApp() call inside the function in your child component, pretty much like what you have done.
4. Dont forget [this](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app#extra-step-needed-when-app-is-not-running) for when the app is not running.

I have not tested this but i dont see a reason why it should not work.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Abdeen M. Going through it now. The link you provide to `this` seems to be broken - I just get `about:blank#blocked`. Could you check the link url? thanks.

Comment: hey @Mr.Robot, you are most welcome. just fixed the broken link. cheers!

Comment: Thanks - I am.doing all of the above but cannot get it to work unfortunately :(