# Launch Android App from other Android App without losing current state while in background in Android Native

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Consider there are two Android Native Apps "A" and "B" having Activities as A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2, B3 respectively where A1 and B1 are the Launcher Activities for respective Applications

Use Case: App **"A"** is Launched and user navigates to **A2** from **A1** and puts the app in background
User now opens App **"B"** and navigates to **B2** from **B1**. There is a button present on **B2** which will open App **"A"**. Here Since the App **"A"** is in background and on **A2** Activity, The App should start from same State, i.e. from **A2** only

If App **"A"** is not in background, then it will start from **A1** i.e. the Launcher Activity

Code tried so far

Java Code

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.target");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This code is Launching **"A"** App from the background but doesn't maintains the state and hence starts from the Launcher Activity

Already tried this solution, but doesn't works either
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075313/6617467

Comment: Are you using INTENT to come out from **B** App?You can just come out from **B** App instead of using intent. System OS will automatically show **A** App in its current state

Comment: checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application

Comment: S. Ambika, Yes I have to use Intent only, as I need to launch that specific app from another app

Comment: Then you should use `putExtras` along with Intent and handle it on **A** App launcher screen side.

Comment: S.Ambika, that's secondary part, I'm ofcourse gonna use putExtras, but first challenge is to maintain the state as it is

Comment: @Bijoy, that solution doesn't works

Comment: The code you have should work. You can remove the code you are using to add flags to the launch `Intent`, that isn't necessary. Are you launching either of your apps from an IDE (Android Studio)? How are you launching the apps?