# How to navigate back to app previous screen from Foreground Service(Button click)

Tags: android, service, android-jetpack-navigation

I am launching YouTube with our floating window timer.

when time finishes, I want to come back to the app. Currently I am doing this by startIntent(MainActivity) but it open a fresh app that is an issue, I want to open previous opened fragment.

I used **Single Activity** *Navigation Component Architecture* in my App

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add flag in your intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```