# How to make the app as launcher and the only open app in Android?

Tags: android, android-launcher, rooted-device

Is there a way to make my app the only running app in a device, what I mean is the only visible and open app? Once the device booted, the app will launch automatically while any tap to settings at status bar, back, home and recent apps button are disabled. Probably a custom Android OS is required or rooting the device will be enough? We plan to have a set of devices where users can only operate with one app. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Comment: This might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button

Answer (score 3):

You need to be able to remove current launcher app to the system part of the device.

Then it's as simple as:

- Adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` and
  `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />` to your intent filter

The end result should look similar to this:

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
                android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: yes but how about when user taps home button or open other apps?

Comment: If you don't have any other android app installed, the device will use this one. And if the user taps on home button, it won't be exited I believe. Give it a go and you'll see :)

Comment: But you can still uninstall it

Comment: Not if you make it a system app and prevent user from doing so. Basically the same way you can replace default Android launcher app, somebody can do the same to your launcher app.

Comment: But user can still navigate around aside from my app right?

Comment: I don't think I understand. If you set your app as the launcher app, it will function the exact way as app launcher does on Android. You can for example show other apps, you can do custom widgets and whatnot, depends on your needs. But the user can't quit your app when it's set as a launcher

Comment: Is there a way to treat it as system app or rooting the device is the only easiest way?

Comment: It is the only way. Without rooting, you can't put an app to system folder.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS if you are happy with the answer, please mark it as accepted