# Can another app be started from a backgrounded MAUI app?

Tags: maui

I know that Launcher.OpenAsync("app") can launch another app in the foreground. Is this acceptable from an app that is in a background state across the platforms?

Comment: I’d be a little surprise if it worked, but it should be easy enough to test

Comment: If it doesn’t work, then maybe [bring app to front programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12074980/199364), then launch the ither app?

Comment: From my testing, the app is not launched from the backgrounded code.

Comment: Hi @MarcGeorge, what do you mean by words `from the backgrounded code`?  Could you please post more code snippets?

Comment: That varies per OS, but the basic concept is a state of app where it has no UI, is not visually present at the moment(minimized) or not on the top stack of apps, i.e., doesn't have focus. In my project, I have a separate set of classes that operate entirely independently from the main app when those states are encountered.