# How to set value on android barcode apps?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am doing a QR code scanner. Using calling other apps(ZXING) to scan, so now I am going to set a qrcode value like "12345"(text). When my apps scan the value will jump to next layout. So what code should I add on? How to add?

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
    // Handle successful scan
} else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // Handle cancel
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what you understand by "jump to next layout"? Do you want to start an activity?

Comment: I am a beginner. Sorry for that, mean that after the code be accepted will go to another page or layout. Yup, start an activity. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)