# Android Button click go to another xml page

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-activity

So what I've done in Eclipse, in layouts I have: activity_main.xml  and activity_main2.xml. What I tried is to create a button in activity_main.xml and on click to go on screen of activity_main2.xml

so in `com.example.myfirstapp` I have

MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void click1(View v) {
        Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
        Intent i=new Intent(
                     MainActivity.this,
                     MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

MainActivity2.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity

Comment: please research more on tutorial regarding this. there are bunch on the web..

Comment: Have you given android:onClick="click1" property for button in activity_main.xml?

Comment: @user1956735 Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Comment: There is more than one way to do this.

Comment: FYI before you post a very simple and juvenile question on Stackoverflow, make sure to see if the question hasn't already been answered and to do some research before posting. A lack of research is frowned upon. Trust me, been there, done that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write below code in your MainActivity.java file instead of your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtn1);
        mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And Declare MainActivity2 into your Androidmanifest.xml file using below code.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
</activity>
```

Comment: in which Androidmanifest.xml do i need to add                                                                         <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
</activity>

Comment: There is only 1 Androidmanifest.xml file in your application, please see this link for detail about Androidmanifest.xml file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Change your FirstyActivity to:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn_go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
            btn_go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
              Intent i=new Intent(
                     MainActivity.this,
                     MainActivity2.class);
              startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this.

Here is a good resource straight from Google:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

At developer.android.com, they have numerous tutorials explaining just about everything you need to know about android. They even provide detailed API for each class.

If that doesn't help, there are NUMEROUS different resources that can help you with this question and other android questions.

Comment: Right! learning the whole topic is better than finding just an answer