# GridLayout - showing basic info from data in sqlite

Tags: android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I had another description, but I am going direct to the point editing now, its better this way:

- I need to select and display 10 attributes from the sqlite database, for now only string types.

Questions:

1) I will need to create a king of grid, to fill with a ListView (BaseAdapter)?

Posted a pic of the result, client expect.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, I assume that you want to display your data on an activity correct?
here is the link that expalins it
[Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)

Comment: Tks for answering. In fact to deal with the navigation and intents im okay... I just need to create a Grid and display data from objects that contains this data.

Comment: an answer that is only a link is not usually a good answer. Can you summarize some of the key points that are covered there and edit them into this answer so that a reader can decide whether to follow the link or not?