# How to switch to another Activity using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, imagebutton

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
        ImageButton x = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        x.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                com.example.choiceisaseriousmatter.MainActivity.this,
                Choice.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
        // present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code is for switching to another `Activity` when the `imageButton` is clicked. But whenever I click on the button the program just crashes.

Comment: Please post errors from LogCat.

Comment: Add `@Override` before the `onClick` function a well. Since you are implementing it, you might need to override.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri adding `Override` does not matter here...

Comment: you should add more info to your question. is `Choice` is an `Activity` class (does extends `Activity`)? if yes, have you declared it in manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Are you already override the onClick method? Try this change:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Choice.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `Choice` `Activity` to the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

```
<activity android:name=".Choice" />
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity) is very similar.