# How to run another application from current application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

IDE: Eclipse, java, Android

Hi, I have 2 android applications App1, App2. In App1 I have created a button and on clicking this button I want to launch another android application.

```
//For performing this i have created button and a event Code is below

  btnotherAppLaunch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent("com.example.addsubtract");


        }
    });
```

Here addsubtract is my simple App2.
When i am clicking on button nothing is happening. pls suggest what i am missing I am new in android app development

Comment: plz do google first, its very basic    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/

Comment: It is basic, but your link is about Activities, not Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way (may need to replace getActivity() with whatever is appropriate to the place you are calling (like MainActivity.this or something)):

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.addsubtract");
getActivity().startActivity(it);
```