# want to create a login page in android that will have a login button and on clicking the button it will redirect to another layout

Tags: android

Want to create a log_in page in android that will have a **login** button and on clicking the button it will redirect to another layout . The second layout will have a **logout** button that will redirect to the first layout. Then if user presses back button in emulator then he will not be redirected to second layout. Will be grateful to see some suggestions or answers. Thank you..

Comment: Will be great to see what you have so far and a direct **question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try things out first and if they do not work out then you can post your question. Anyway you can create an empty activity, customise the layout as needed then override the onClick() method on the the button to redirect to a second activity. More details here:

[Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)

Comment: thank you, it helped a lot, actually i tried by myself but i m having problem  to post my code..