# adding intent to checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have checkboxes in my activity A.

I want to know is that if a user checks one of the given box, then I would like to link that to another activity so as when a user checks the box he goes to that activity B, similarly all the other boxes are linked to different activities.

I tried the code for intent in buttons but that doesn't seem to work. 
If i can get the particular code and the imports, that would be very helpful thanks in advance.

```
public void onClick(View view){
Intent i = new Intent(this, 2nd java.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

I use the above one for buttons.

Comment: Describe your exact problem

Comment: whats the code to do the above

Comment: implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener inyour activity

Comment: Dont forget to add  checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) in your activity

Comment: thanks jinu, also can the code that i gave above be used for a radio button

Comment: Is your target name valid?  `2nd java.class`??

Comment: @Rustam that was just an example

Comment: use boolean in mehod to check it is checked or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your code to add on below listener :

```
 yourCheckboxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (isChecked){
                   Intent i = new Intent(this, 2nd java.class);
                   startActivity(i);
            }
        }

    });
```

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox chk= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            FirstActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```